# Missing get data from web

Tags: excel

I'm trying to get data from a stocks website and add it to my Excel But unfortunately, I'm unable to find **From Web** in the data ribbon section. Is something wrong with my excel? I use 2016 version.

Here is a screenshot of the same.

[image]

Comment: From HTML should be what you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

The `From HTML` should be the `from web` you are looking for.

Try the `From HTML`.